# How to create menu for opening other pycharm files?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

I have made two games with python tkinter (tic tac toe and snakes). Could someone help me create a menu from which I could choose what game to play (planning to code more than two games). Does the menu have to be a separate .py file and do I need to import the gamefiles to that menufile?

Comment: have those two games as two separate functions, then have buttons that call each functions.

Comment: you could import the different games using `import [name of .py file]` (make sure the files are in the same file directory, or you can write the full path to the other .py files.) then make buttons which call the imported games.